# Log level for wildfly cargo container

Tags: maven, wildfly, cargo

I am using maven cargo container to deploy wildfly and run some test.

```
<container.groupId>org.wildfly</container.groupId>
<container.artifactId>wildfly-dist</container.artifactId>
<container.version>17.0.1.Final</container.version>
```

I want to change the default log level because default is to verbose. How can i do that?

Comment: What do you want to reduce the logging on the plugin or WildFly itself?

Comment: Wildlfy which is started by the plugin

Comment: You'd have to configure WildFly then. I don't know much about the cargo plugin, but you can use the [wildfly-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/2.0.1.Final/) to execute CLI commands.